# LinkedIn post inspector giving 500 failure

Tags: nginx, https, linkedin-api, gunicorn

I run a blogging website. I am trying to share blogs on LinkedIn. When I inspect post on LinkedIn post inspector, it gives 500 error. I am not sure what could be wrong as I have included meta tags and I am able to post the same URL on Facebook without any error.

I read from some previous posts that there could be some problems with the SSL handshake. But I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I am also having this problem. In my case, it's occurring with the following Cloudfront site: https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/d3gy42k9afxymg.cloudfront.net. The LinkedIn crawler hits a 500 when trying to look at it. I am urgently needing to fix this - anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @lou1989 what was the issue?

Comment: I never really got to the bottom of it. I solved it by getting Cloudfront to immediately return a simple HTML file with metas when crawled by bots. I think the problem was related to my complex Cloudfront set up

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with you but after 1-hour fixing, I know how to solve it.
You just have to add `<!doctype html>` to line 1 of every file which execute the page. Then use Linkedin post inspector to see if problem is fixed. https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/

Comment: This still works in 2022. Note that I had this in line one of my file with different capitalization and it didn't work. Changing it to exactly as written in this comment fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem on my website as well, for me the problem was HTML-minification related.

Linkedin doesn't parse the short doctype `<!doctypehtml>` so you'll probably get a 500 server error if this is in your page.