# LinkedIn's post inspector don't work on main page, only subpages

Tags: facebook, linkedin-api

I have a website that is not showing some meta data when I share the url on some social media like LinkedIn and Facebook.

By inspecting the url on the [LinkedIn's post inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/) I get the following error:

```
We cannot display a preview for this URL.
Ingestion feedback Error: We encountered a server error while trying to inspect the URL.
URL redirect trail:
1   0 undefined   <url>
```

By debugging it on the Facebook's Debugger, it gives the error: `Curl Timeout: The request to scrape the URL timed out.`

The thing is, if I inspect some subpages from this url, the error don't occur. But for some others it still does.

I've checked the meta tags on the main page and they are all there.

I've also tried the suggestion of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64411958/18635794), but it didn't work.

And, finally, I've read things about ssl handshake but I didn't get how could I test it.

Anyone has nay idea of how to solve this issue?

Comment: What does the Facebook debugger say? Can we get the actual URL to the site, being able to check this "live" is probably quicker, then trying to go over possible causes "in theory."

Comment: Hi @CBroe! I've updated the question with the live url and the result from Facebook's debugger. I've also changed the lines where I said that the inspection worked for subpages, because I've tested it again and it works for some but not for others.

Comment: Your pages load very slow, in my browser both take longer than I would normally be willing to wait around as a user. You're going to need to look into what causes these long response times, and how you can speed things up.